# Stack Overflow jobs does not list all books. Is there a way to add missing ones?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

When trying to add a book to my cv with ISBN 978-953-307-078-0, the search returns no results.

This in turn does not let me add that book to my CV. Is there any other way to add the book to Stack Overflow database of books?

Comment: This book was written by "Félix Jesús Villanueva Molina", not "Jorge Torres".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Can't tell if joking or not. Some people don't use their real name online.

Comment: @cybermonkey: Scandalous! Both of us clearly have! (I'm not joking; more prompting)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The book was _edited_ by Mr. Molina - Jorge Torres is listed as an author for the third chapter.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As employee Jason Punyon points out in another answer, Stack Overflow Jobs pulls book information from Amazon. This means you need to ensure that Amazon knows about your book. If you have written a book that has an ISBN but does not appear on Amazon, try these two steps:

1. Give Amazon some basic information about your book by [creating a Selling on Amazon account](http://services.amazon.com/selling/getting-started.htm/ref=asus_soa_snav_how) and then offering at least one copy of your book for sale. You might even get a few sales this way.
2. [Join Author Central](https://authorcentral.amazon.com/gp/help?ie=UTF8&topicID=200620850) and [add your book](https://authorcentral.amazon.com/gp/help?ie=UTF8&topicID=200777990). An author page on Amazon helps users discover other books that you have written. In addition, comments to the question mention being a contributor to a collective work; claiming co-authorship this way should help clarify cases of co-authorship like this.

Answer (score -15):

We use the Amazon API for book search and book images and it appears that book isn't in their database. Sorry, but there's no other way to add it.

Comment: Hey, can you have a look into the [OL API](https://openlibrary.org/developers/api). It has a larger list of books. :)

Comment: I don't know the right way to deal with this, but I think it's pretty clear that Amazon doesn't have everything, so using Amazon's API as the final arbiter of what is or isn't allowed is probably not a good long-term plan.

Comment: I couldn't have written my answer without yours. I wonder whether downvoters are complaining about your answer's tone.

Comment: @tepples The downvotes probably mean "We don't agree with you restricting to the use of Amazon API" more than the answer's tone (which I find perfectly fine).

Comment: I am kind of curious why this is so heavily downvoted. Is it because people don't like that this is how SO currently works?

Comment: @Gimby No, it's because people love to get the hump than to actually try to help making something better.