# How to mention research papers/publication on Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Simply, where and how can one mention a publication or a co-authored research paper on Stack Overflow Careers.

Please feel free to edit the tags or move the question to right community.

Comment: I don't think you can specifically unless there is a free text field where you can put it. You can't even list a book you co-authored unless the book is "known". http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313566/stack-overflow-jobs-does-not-list-all-books-is-there-a-way-to-add-missing-ones

Comment: I'd add it as an "Experience" entry

Comment: I personally put them in the "WRITING" section under articles and blog, with links to the publisher's site (usually the citation page a DOI would resolve to as well). From there anyone interested could get further information about authors, co-authors and what not.